# How do I intercept and change password field values on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply a password hash to all password fields before the form is submitted. So far what I have is this...

```
$("#loginform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=password]').each(function(){
        console.log($.sha256($(this).val())) //Hash password
        //Set password back
    });
    return true;
});
```

... which will intercept the submission and hash the password, but I cannot replace the plaintext password in the input box using normal methods.

I know how to do this with hidden inputs and the like, but I am applying this to a site that already has a fairly solid login structure in place, so I want to make the HTML modifications to a minimum.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just make the login call AJAX-wise.

Comment: I could do that, I was hoping to do it in this manner because there are about 10 forms that need the client-side hashing, all making calls to different PHP files. I am trying to make something more universal.

Comment: Why not do the hashing on the server? There's no security from sending the hashed password; if someone intercepts it, they can send the same hashed password themselves.

Comment: The answer on this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837714/jquery-how-to-submit-a-form-with-edited-user-inputed-values?rq=1

Comment: Well you just make each request to `$(form).attr('action')`, after giving each form a common `.pleaseHashMe` class for example ^^. btw, isn't it just better to use HTTPS than hash stuff client side? I think a dictionary attack with sniffed hash and algorithm isn't an unlikely scenario, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the point of the client-side hashing is to secure the passwords going over an unsecure connection (HTTP), make sure you use a salt and a random 'challenge'.

Like so:

response = sha256(challenge + sha265(salt + password))

The server knows challenge, salt and the answer to sha265(salt + password), it can then validate the response.

You need salt + password to avoid rainbow attacks, and the response / challenge to prevent replay attacks.

A better approach would be to just use SSH ;)